# CSS - Styling icons

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i need to make my icons `<a href="">` but i dont know how

```
      <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="imgbg"><a href="#"><img src="images/nonsteam.jpg"></a></td>
          <td class="icon"></td>
          <td class="download-name"><a href="#">Counter Strike 1.6 Nonsteam</a></td>
          <td class="download-category">Counter-Strike / Jebat / Mrdat / Nonsteam / Hra </td>
          <td class="imgbg"><div class="download-icon"></div></td>
          <a href="#"><td class="comment-icon"></td></a>
      </tr>
```

CSS:

```
#downloads .download-icon{
    background-image: url("images/dark_download.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 34px;
    height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 13px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#downloads .comment-icon{
    background-image: url("images/dark_buble.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 33px;
    height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 24px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Your markup is wrong at least in the last line... the `a` tag must not be out side the `td`!

Comment: I know that, it was try to make whole <td> as href

Comment: Put the `a` inside the `td` and give it `display: block;` as style

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my try looks like: 
<td class="comment-icon" a href="#"></td> but its not working :(

Comment: No... Create an `a` *element* inside a `td` element: `<td class="comment-icon"><a href="#">bla</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `td` to be clickable then you can either

```
<td class="comment-icon" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.co.in'"></td>
```

or

```
<td class="icon"></td>
JAVASCRIPT:        
$('.icon').click(function () {
   alert('blue-theme');
});
```

But you can not change the format of `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` and hence you were not able to have `a` tag before the `td` tag.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/sGW7K/1/)